# C - How can I concatenate an array of strings into a buffer?

Tags: c

I am trying to concatenate a random number of lines from the song twinkle twinkle. Into the buffer before sending it out because I need to count the size of the buffer.

My code:

```
char temp_buffer[10000];
char lyrics_buffer[10000];
char *twinkle[20];
int arr_num;
int i;

twinkle[0] = "Twinkle, twinkle, little star,";
twinkle[1] = "How I wonder what you are!";
twinkle[2] = "Up above the world so high,";
twinkle[3] = "Like a diamond in the sky.";
twinkle[4] = "When the blazing sun is gone,";
twinkle[5] = "When he nothing shines upon,";

srand(time(NULL));
arr_num = rand() % 5;

for (i=0; i<arr_num; i++);
{
    sprintf(temp_buffer, "%s\n", twinkle[i]);
    strcat(lyrics_buffer, temp_buffer);
}

printf("%s%d\n", lyrics_buffer, arr_num);
```

My current code only prints 1 line even when I get a number greater than 0.

Comment: Do you initialize `lyrics_buffer` anywhere? If you don't and it's a local variable then using it in `strcat` will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes its a local variable. Should I also declare it in the main?

Comment: `for (i=0; i<arr_num; i++);` remove last `;` and `% 5` --> `% 6`

Comment: maybe `i<arr_num` --> `i<=arr_num`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems: The first was found by BLUEPIXY and it's that your loop never does what you think it does. You would have found this out *very* easily if you just used a debugger to step through the code (please do that first in the future).

The second problem is that contents of non-static local variables (like your `lyrics_buffer` is *indeterminate*. Using such variables without initialization leads to *undefined behavior*. The reason this happens is because the `strcat` function looks for the end of the destination string, and it does that by looking for the terminating `'\0'` character. _If the contents of the destination string is indeterminate it will seem random, and the terminator may not be anywhere in the array.

To initialize the array you simply do e.g.

```
char lyrics_buffer[10000] = { 0 };
```

That will make the compiler initialize it all to zero, which is what `'\0'` is.

This initialization is not needed for `temp_buffer` because `sprintf` unconditionally starts to write at the first location, it doesn't examine the content in any way. It does, in other words, initialize the buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Unfortunately I am not using an IDE. I am using a linux vm machine and I am not a linux user so I am not sure how to use a debugger in linux console.

Comment: will there be any consequence if I initialize temp_buffer anyway? Maybe I will initialize all arrays in the future just to be safe

Comment: @nanjeroechizen Not a problem. There's really only one debugger in the Linux world anyway, and it's the same that is used by the popular Linux IDE': GDB. Try running the command `gdb` or install the `gdb` package.

Comment: @nanjeroechizen Regarding the initialization, it really depends on if the compiler can optimize it in any way, or if it calls e.g. `memset` automatically at the start of the function. It might incur a slight overhead for each call to your function. But for such a small array it won't be noticeable on modern multi-GHz computers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and concise answers. I will install and practice using debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Update the buffer address after each print after initializing buffer with 0.

```
char temp_buffer[10000] = {0};
for (i=0; i<arr_num; i++) //removed semicolon from here
{
    sprintf(temp_buffer + strlen(temp_buffer), "%s\n", twinkle[i]);
}
```

`temp_buffer` should contain final output. Make sure you have enough buffer size

You don't need `strcat`

Comment: @aragaer how exactly?